# Java seperate words and meanings from a file

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to separate the words and meanings from a file and then I want to store
each word in a sqlite (WORDS) table and its corresponding meaning in another (MEANING) table.

The file looks like this.

```
word 1
    explanation 1
    explanation 1
    explanation 1

    explanation 1
word 2
    explanation 2
    explanation 2

    explanation 2
    explanation 2
word 3
    explanation 3
    explanation 3
    explanation 3

    explanation 3
word 4
    explanation 4

    explanation 4

    explanation 4
```

Now the problem is that I cannot figure out how to split the words and meanings in 1 - 1 correspondence. The spaces among the explanation lines should exist even after splitting them.

Here is a sample code what I have tried so far.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
String abbr = "";
String exp = "";
String line;
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    if (!(line = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty() && !(line.startsWith("    "))) {
        abbr = line;
        //Debug
        System.out.println(abbr);
        printExp(exp);
        exp = "";
    } else if (line.isEmpty() || line.startsWith("  ")) {
        exp += line;
    }
}
```

A method used for debugging purpose.

```
public static void printExp(String exp) {
    if (!exp.equals("")) {
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
}
```

You may think of any other simple solution, eg through regex.
Help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: "The file looks like this."  Er, no, that's an image. A text file would have text in it.

Comment: ...and would be easier to experiment with.

Comment: OK. It is just for to keep the layout of the file in mind.

Comment: Something like `^(\w.*)((?:\n(?:$| ).*)*)` might do it for you. [See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cE4rF6/1).

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand correctly, this might do it for you:

```
^(\w.*)((?:\n(?:$|\W).*)*)
```

It captures a line starting with a word character. Then it captures any number of lines starting with a space, or that are empty.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cE4rF6/2).

Comment: You are getting it right. May you employ this in the code above? Thnx